# Use a HTML page like a button

Tags: html

I have a HTML page and I want to use the page like a button, for example when I click anywhere on the page, something happens just like a button, any way?

Comment: Perhaps, have an element with `100% width` and `height`, and wrap `a` tag around the element...

Comment: see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nagq8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bind a `click` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to [the `document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document).

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (evt) { 
    alert('click'); 
});
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, just 1 other problem, except this method, I used a button too. but when I click the button, the function works twice, once because of clicking on the button and once because of using this method , how to solve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: how to use stopPropagation ?

Comment: To quote the page I linked to: See Example 5: Event Propagation in the Examples chapter for a more detailed example of this method and event propagation in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following function to trigger actions when the mouse is clicked anywhere on the page:

```
document.body.onmousedown = function() {
     // enter your code here
}
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, just 1 other problem, except this method, I used a button too. but when I click the button, the function works twice, once because of clicking on the button and once because of using .body.onmousedown , how to solve this?